# Chart.js I can't show all my data in line chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, linechart

I have a line chart in chart.js. I have 7 dates and 39 values. I want to show 39 values but I can only show 7 values. How can I show all values?

data:  ["562.98","499.79","501.34","1908.0783","160.15","68.1","892.0366","66.0","467.66","1598.29","1293.98","1583.694","1182.0","1018.92","436.67","146.44","1898.2472","427.22","204.5917","502.901","1266.3685","1350.3","880.2038","876.7468","2282.9453","12316.584","2122.3929","1842.65","338.54","288.0499","365.0371","357.65","860.664","385.5125","466.645","895.11","160.69","751.4569","1797.4571"],

const labels = ['Feb 14 2023', 'Feb 15 2023', 'Feb 16 2023', 'Feb 17 2023', 'Feb 18 2023', 'Feb 19 2023', 'Feb 20 2023', 'Feb 21 2023'];

```
const data = {
    labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        yAxisID: 'B',
        label: "label",
        data: data,
        borderColor: "#D07EF6",
        backgroundColor: "#D07EF6",
      },
    ],
  };
```

[image: 1]

ı don't find enough example

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the same number of data and labels to paint all data in the chart. If less, the chart will only paint the first data in the dataset to fill the provided labels. If you do not add all the labels, it is impossible to know which data is linked to each date.

Maybe you want to paint all data and only show some labels in the chart. That is possible. But you need all the labels and then filter with an axis callback with Chart.JS to show only that you want.

For your situation, you need to add all the labels. You can try one of these options:

- Add the hour to the date, so you can difference between data in the same day.
- Add an special identifier to each label you dont want to show and then filter using the callback I said before

Also, I think Chart.JS only show some labels that fit in chart´s space, so if you use the first option (and hide the hour using a date formatter, if you do not want to show it), maybe you do not need the callback

Comment: Thank you Alberto. I will try your recommended :)